# Генерирование дерева каталогов

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

**Задача**: автоматизировать создание структуры для проекта.

**Код**:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ABS_PATH="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
Y5=$(seq "$(date +%Y)" "$(($(date +%Y) + 5))" | paste -s -d ",")

DIR_STRUCT=(
  arch/{doc,ISO,bckp}
  soft
  wrkf/{$Y5}
  tlbx
  tmp
)

for dir in ${DIR_STRUCT[@]}; do
  mkdir -p $dir
done
```

```bash
tree -d

.
├── arch
│   ├── bckp
│   ├── doc
│   └── ISO
├── soft
├── tlbx
├── tmp
└── wrkf
    └── {2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023}

9 directories
```

**Проблема**: Как видно из примера, не создается список годов, где-то лишние экранирующие кавычки, т.к. после того как убрал их из `DIR_STRUCT` структура `arch` получилась, а вот для `wrkf` распознает как целую строку.

Comment: Прочитайте про рекурсию.

Comment: @And в каком контексте? ветка arch создалась wrkf нет, тут что то другое.

Comment: Что, что-то другое? читайте про рекурсионное создание директорий, причем тут `wlkf`.

Comment: @And это в bash-shell? mkdir создает рекурсивно, проблема в переменного DIR_STRUCT

Comment: А года разве не пробелами должны разделяться, чтобы восприниматься раздельно?

Comment: @donRumata глянь ветку для `arch` она без проблем создалась. Года генерируются динамически относительно текущего, может там что то лишнее, пока не не нашел.